# Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

**i have problem in grpc C#**
repeated field

**in grpc proto**

```
message RpcResponseListAccountModel{
    int32 status = 1;
    repeated AccountItem Content = 2;
}
```

when response is

```
IList<AccountItem> retVal = new List<AccountItem>();
return new RpcResponseListAccountModel
{
 Status = 1,
 Content = retVal // i can't set Content because say
}
```

because say :
Property or indexer property cannot be assigned to  it is read only in C#

**why ?!!**

Answer (score 4):

It is a get-only collection property - similar to (but not exactly):

```cs
partial class RpcResponseListAccountModel
{
    public List<AccountItem> Content { get; } = new List<AccountItem>();
    // ...
}
```

Instead of trying to *assign a new collection*: add to the existing:

```cs
return new RpcResponseListAccountModel
{
 Status = 1,
 Content = { someItemToAdd }
};
```

which is semantically equivalent to:

```cs
var obj = new RpcResponseListAccountModel();
obj.Status = 1;
obj.Content.Add(someItemToAdd);
return obj;
```

If you don't want any items (as per your empty list example), you don't need to touch `Content` at all:

```cs
return new RpcResponseListAccountModel
{
 Status = 1
};
```